Isomorphism Reflexive Spaces
This afternoon I have been trying to try this exercise from a Book of Functional Analysis, but I have not obtained any results. I quote the exercise.
Let $E$ and $F$ be Banach spaces.
a) Prove that if $E$ is reflexive, then $E \cong F$ if and only if $E^* \cong F^*$.
(Here, $\cong$ denotes a continuous linear isomorphism with continuous inverse)
b) Does the previous statement hold if $E$ is not reflexive? Provide a proof if true, or a counterexample if false.
For a), there is a relatively simple direction. But, for the another, Do I have to prove that F is a reflective space?
Maybe for b) i have to consider the $\ell^1$ space. this is possibly a counterexample.

Welcome! What is your definition of reflexive? And what have you tried so far?

@user326210 Hello! Thanks a lot. My definition for a Reflexive Space is that $\forall \phi \in E^{**}, \ \exists x \in E \text{ tal que } \phi = J_x$. In other words, that the canonical injection is surjective.

For (a), hint: try proving $E$ is reflexive iff $E^\ast$ is. The forward direction should be relatively easy. For the backwards direction, argue by contradiction - if $E$ is not reflexive, then use Hahn-Banach to get some $\varphi \in E^{\ast\ast\ast}$ which restricts to $0$ on $E$ and obtain a contradiction. After that, (a) follows easily.

For (b), indeed a counterexample exists with $E^\ast = F^\ast = \ell^1$. See, for example, Corollary 3 in https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Spaces-of-continuous-functions-(IV).-(On-of-spaces-Bessaga-Pe%C5%82czy%C5%84ski/d38db1a6d810b7d756cff09cc038b2082b13ec24 , or https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02762798

@MarkCarpio It is basic courtesy in this site to accept and upvote answers which are helpful to you. That is the only way you reward the user who has taken time and devoted an effort to answer your question/query. You have not done so in any of your posts.

The implication that if $E\simeq F$ then $E^*\simeq F^*$ is always true. Hence if $E^*\simeq F^*$, then $E^{**}\simeq F^{**}$. To finish the argument you also need to know that $F$ is reflexive. This follows from the fact that a Banach space is reflexive if and only if its dual is reflexive.
For the converse to fail, you need an example of non-isomorphic spaces that have the same dual. Indeed $\ell^1$ is an example of a space that is the dual of many non-isomorphic spaces (for instance, $C(X)$ for $X$ countable and compact), but I'm not aware of an entirely trivial example.

I think your answer is incomplete for part (a). To prove the backwards direction, you also need to prove $F \simeq F^{\ast\ast}$, as the OP is only assuming $E$ is reflexive.

Very good point! I have clarified that.
